# Jquery Delay Function Calls

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services

I'm trying to find a way to delay all code that takes place after I make a service call.  The reason for this delay is that my service returns code necesarry for the following functions and the result I pass is to these following functions is undefined.

I have tried attaching the setTimeout() to the function that is called directly after the service call, but then it just skips the function I set the timeout on and jumps to the next function...My web method that I am calling is not that big and is not doing anything that is too intensive

```
public bool GetSpreadsheetStatusForAdmin(string cacId)
    {
        SpreadSheetStatus result = new SpreadSheetStatus();
        List<Data.Spreadsheet> spreadsheets = SpreadsheetManager.GetUserSpreadsheets(GetCurrent.Identity);
        if (spreadsheets.Count != 0)
        {
            foreach (Data.Spreadsheet spreadsheet in spreadsheets)
            {
                if (spreadsheet.Status == SpreadsheetStatus.Pending)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I had found the delay() and thought that might work, but I don't have jquery 1.4 and can't use it as of yet.

is there anything that can help..?

Comment: Not clear what the problem is. The code you show is not javascript, eh?  I guess it is a server-side method, that is invoked over json?  But you are asking about how to delay in the browser.  So the code you show is probably irrelevant, right?   Could you show the actual browser-side code where you want to do the delay?

Comment: I can't get the code to post correctly in the form.. so I hope yuo can make it out..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. i couldn't ever get the function to delay and I couldn't use the onCallback to call the functions I wanted to delay.  So I ended up setting the value I wanted to get when I load the page.  I'm setting the values on the rows instead.. it's not exactly what I wanted to do, but it works.  My page does load a fraction of a second slower too..

Answer (score 3):

Call the function as a callback of your service call.  How are you calling your service?

Answer (score 0):

here is some of the code..

the GetCheckedOutFieldingsForUser is the service call I was referring to in my post. The two EditUser functions below are the functions I would like to delay.. if I put the delay on the `setTimeout('$popup.load("Forms/EditUserForm.htm #EditUserForm", null, function() { EditUserLoaded(cacId, onSaveCallback); });', 1000);` it skips to the EditUserLoaded, which doesnt give the proper results

`function EditUser(id, onSaveCallback)
{
    $("#EditUserPopup").remove();
    var $popup = $("<div id='EditUserPopup'></div>");
    $("body").append($popup);
    $popup.load("Forms/EditUserForm.htm #EditUserForm", null, function() { EditUserLoaded(cacId, onSaveCallback); });
}`

```
function EditUserLoaded(id, onSaveCallback)
```

{
    $("#EditUserCancelButton").click(function() { ShotdownEditUserForm() });

```
alert(isCheckedOut + "EditUserLoaded");
CallMfttService("ServiceLayer/UserManager.asmx/GetUser", "{id:'" + id + "'}", function(result)
{
    if (!userIsAdmin)
    {
        $("#EditUserForm input").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#EditUserForm select").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#EditUserFormHeader').text("View User");
        $("#EditUserCancelButton").text("Close");
        $("#EditUserSaveButton").hide();
    }
    else 
    {
        if (isCheckedOut == "True")
        {
            $("#EditUserOrganization").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }

        $("#EditUserSaveButton").click(function() { SaveUser(id, onSaveCallback); }).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do.  Please edit your original question deleting anything that isn't relevant and properly formatting the code.

Answer (score 0):

After rereading my original post I see it looks confusing as hell...
what I ended up doing was; creating a second method getUserRecords that got a 'flag', I call getUserRecords from my first, getUser method and return a new object type with the flag included in the new object.